# How can I simulate a connection from a different location

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, server

I am having some latency issues with my game server running on the amazon ec2 instance. My game runs fine with multiple clients in the same physical location but when I tried to play the game against my friend there is significant latency (My friend lives in Northern California and I live in Southern California). I need to find a way to simulate a client connection from a different location so I can debug my server's latency issues but I don't know how to do that. Is there a tool or something that could redirect the packets I'm sending to a server in northern california and then redirect it to the amazon server? That would help me test latency and the effect of physical location of the internet connection. Can proxys or vpns be used for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can use a VPN. Please do not add answers linking to various VPN providers, we don't do lists, or ads or lists of ads here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vyprVPN available [here](https://vyprvpnforwindows.en.softonic.com/)

With this you can select a geolocation and then it will simulate a connection from a different location

Comment: So I ended up using a mobile app called Betternet which let's you connect your smartphone from over 70 servers across the U.S. and it's working really well and was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It would be a really good answer if you explained what VPNs can do and end in "just pick a provider of your choice" or something similar. As it stands, the whole question/answer combinations smells like spam. Maybe you can edit and improve your answer?